# Converting python string to gdb.Value for GDB pretty printing

Tags: python, gdb

when i try to return a python string as part of the children of a GDB prettyprinter, it returns as a char array. Is there a way i can return it as a normal string ?

I have a pretty printer like this

```py
class APrinter:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.name = "a name"
        self.age = age

    def children(self):
        yield ('name', self.name)
        yield ('age', self.age)
        yield ('address', 'this is an address')

    def display_hint(self):
        return 'array'
```

in this case name and address would return as a char array in an ide

i also tried converting it to a gdb Value

```py
yield ('address', gdb.Value('this is an address'))
```

from the api [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html), but it returns the same result

[image: result]

however when i put it in the `to_string` method it prints out normally like this

```py
def to_string(self):
    return 'this is an address'
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Because usually char arrays are automatically shown as a string as well.

Comment: @ssbssa I tried it in `vscode`, `clion` and `kdevelop` it's all printed as a char array

Comment: You could try changing `display_hint` to "map", instead of "array".

Comment: @darcamo i tried that it does not do anything

Comment: Looks like an issue with the IDE. In gdb console it works well. ■ that having said, try casting it to `char*` like this `gdb.Value(...).cast(gdb.lookup_type("char").pointer())`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me, at least, based on the idea of @user202729.
The problem with @user202729's original idea by itself, however, is that at least my CLion will not have a zero delimiter at the end of the string, even if I try to hard code it in python and then the debugging window shows lots of bugs due to access to memory behind the unterminated string.

To fix this, you can convert your python strings to readable `char*` strings like this:

```cpp
def make_char_pointer(string):
    original_bytes = string.encode("UTF-8")
    original = gdb.Value(original_bytes + b"\0", gdb.lookup_type("char").array(len(original_bytes)))
    adjusted = original.cast(gdb.lookup_type("char").pointer())
    return adjusted
```

I arrived at this point by reading the relevant parts of the GDB python API documentation which you can currently find here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html

Generally the idea is that you can construct a `gdb.Value` with 2 arguments, the second being the type and the first being a python buffer. GDB then creates a new instance of that type (which in this case is basically a `char[len(string)+1]` if you evaluate the `len` there as python expression) and writes the buffer into that. Now we cast that to `char*` and BAÄM, we are done :D ... only took me a couple of hours to get this right for my own project ... piece o'cake